# Deploying a static site built from Create React App on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, create-react-app

### Edit

Ok so I changed the run command to `ls -la && serve -s build` to make sure the build folder exists, and it turns out the folder doesn't exist and that's obviously why it was failing to serve.

Why is my `build` folder not coming through? I thought the build folder should be created during the build phase (like it does when i run `npm build` locally) and then forwarded to Elastic Beanstalk because I specified "**/*" in `buildspec.yml`.

### Background

I'm trying to deploy my personal blog website created from `create-react-app` on `elastic beanstalk` on AWS. I've set up the code pipeline and code pipeline works (tested with the example application). With my own app, everything works (no red flag), except that the server is failing to serve the website for some reason. It shows `404 | The requested path could not be found` error.

### Basic Structure

The pipeline:

github -> aws codebuild -> aws elastic beanstalk

I have a very simple react app which is a simple website. I basically build this react app (`npm run build`), and serve using `serve` npm package using `serve -s build` command. I used to host this in `Heroku` and it worked fine. (If I upload the same codebase that does **not** work on `Elastic Beanstalk` to `Heroku`, it works fine.)

### What I tried

So if I look at the logs, it all works fine and log even says: **Accepting connections at http://localhost:8080**. Logs:

```
Jan 19 03:26:12 ip-172-31-37-45 web: > my-blog@0.1.0 serve /var/app/current
Jan 19 03:26:12 ip-172-31-37-45 web: > serve -s ./
Jan 19 03:26:13 ip-172-31-37-45 web: INFO: Accepting connections at http://localhost:8080
Jan 19 03:31:25 ip-172-31-37-45 web: INFO: Gracefully shutting down. Please wait...
Jan 19 03:31:29 ip-172-31-37-45 web: > my-blog@0.1.0 serve /var/app/current
Jan 19 03:31:29 ip-172-31-37-45 web: > serve -s ./build
Jan 19 03:31:29 ip-172-31-37-45 web: INFO: Accepting connections at http://localhost:8080
```

So I tried to just put a very simple `index.html` file in the root directory, and tried to serve it using the same structure except now the serve command is `serve -s ./` to serve from the root. And it worked!

But if I change serve command to `serve -s build` then it shows `404 | The requested path could not be found` error.

serve command serves `index.html` in the folder, and the build folder has it... not sure what is wrong. Any help will be greatly appreciated!!

### ETC

In case my buildspec is wrong:

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - echo Installing source NPM dependencies...
      - npm install
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Build started on `date`
      - npm run build
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Build completed on `date`
artifacts:
  files:
    - '**/*'
```

I'm just sending all files to elastic beanstalk for now.

Comment: which Elastic Beanstalk platform that you use?

Comment: Hey Raslan thanks for comment. I'm using "Node.js 14 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2"

Comment: did you configure package.json file so that Elastic Beanstalk install the required packages? read here for more info: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_nodejs.html

Comment: @SharuzzamanAhmatRaslan Yeah packages are installed during build process I think. I have updated the question and it looks like the problem is that the"build" folder which is (should be) generated during the build phase is not carried over to Elastic Beanstalk.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so it was my configuration in `code pipeline`. In the sequence of `Source -> Build -> Deploy`, we define for each stage, what input data to use. In my case, my `Deploy` step was still using output from `Source` stage, not the build artifact. What I had to do is:

1. Go to AWS pipeline settings
2. Edit the `build` stage: I gave a name to the output of build stage (in case of me I named it to be `build`). FYI, initially it was empty.
3. Edit the `deploy` stage: I switched the input source from the output of `Source` to the output of `build` (which is the name you used in Step 2).

Then all was well.

In my case, when I created my pipeline I only created `Source` and `Deploy` steps at first, and then added the `build` stage later. So I guess `deploy` was initialised to take input from `Source`.

So it was pretty much just my mistake and lack of understanding of how pipeline works. *Ouch.*

Hope it helps someone, somewhere, someday.